# Is it possible to register multiple Elasticsearch snapshot repositories for the same S3 bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to create separate Elasticsearch snapshot repositories for each major Elasticsearch version, however I don't necessarily want to create separate backing S3 buckets.

I'd like to know if is it okay to use the same bucket for multiple snapshot repositories or will there be any conflicts or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **different repository s3 path** for different elasticsearch versions.

Till you use different base path for each Elasticsearch cluster snapshot repositories irrespective of bucket name, then it's fine.

There are many breaking changes in repository meta-deta files across major elasticsearch version release, hence you can't use same repository path across elasticsearch version. If you do so, repository will get corrupted.